# Can not connect to postgres with asyncpg - "socket.gaierror"

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, asyncpg

I am trying to connect to `PostgreSQL` with `asyncpg` and `SQLAlchemy`. `PostgreSQL` instance is run by `Docker`.

My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/src/db/fill_data.py", line 17, in <module>
    asyncio.run(execute())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 684, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/src/db/fill_data.py", line 12, in execute
    await session.execute(text(file.read()))
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py", line 452, in execute
    result = await greenlet_spawn(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 197, in greenlet_spawn
    result = context.throw(*sys.exc_info())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2306, in execute
    return self._execute_internal(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2181, in _execute_internal
    conn = self._connection_for_bind(bind)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2050, in _connection_for_bind
    return trans._connection_for_bind(engine, execution_options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 2, in _connection_for_bind
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 139, in _go
    ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1144, in _connection_for_bind
    conn = bind.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3279, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3303, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 449, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1263, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 712, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 179, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 177, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 390, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 674, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 900, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 896, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 643, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 937, in connect
    await_only(creator_fn(*arg, **kw)),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 127, in await_only
    return current.driver.switch(awaitable)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 192, in greenlet_spawn
    value = await result
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 2329, in connect
    return await connect_utils._connect(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 1017, in _connect
    raise last_error or exceptions.TargetServerAttributeNotMatched(
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 991, in _connect
    conn = await _connect_addr(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 828, in _connect_addr
    return await __connect_addr(params, True, *args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 873, in __connect_addr
    tr, pr = await connector
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/SQLAlchemyTraining/venv/include/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 744, in _create_ssl_connection
    tr, pr = await loop.create_connection(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1077, in create_connection
    infos = await self._ensure_resolved(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1453, in _ensure_resolved
    return await loop.getaddrinfo(host, port, family=family, type=type,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 898, in getaddrinfo
    return await self.run_in_executor(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/socket.py", line 963, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Here is docker-compose:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:16-alpine
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
```

`.env` file:

```
POSTGRES_USER=tuser
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=tpass
POSTGRES_HOST=db
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_DB=tdb
```

Code to establish connection:

```
def create_engine() -> AsyncEngine:
    engine = create_async_engine(f"postgresql+asyncpg://tuser:tpass@db:5432/tdb", echo=True)
    return engine


def get_async_session(engine: AsyncEngine = create_engine()) -> async_sessionmaker[AsyncSession]:
    return async_sessionmaker(engine)
```

And code I am trying to execute:

```
async def execute() -> None:
    pool = get_async_session()
    with open("chinook_postgres.sql") as file:
        async with pool() as session:
            await session.execute(text(file.read()))
            await session.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(execute())
```